# Problemas para gerar APK em Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, mobile

Estou tentando gerar um arquivo .apk do meu pro projéto android.

Sempre consegui normalmente mas depois que atualizei ele não consegui mais. Isso que atualizei em duas maquinas diferentes.

Quando vou gerar o .apk, aparece a imagem a baixo e clico em V2(Full PAK Signatur)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu gerar o APK, quando vou testar em algum dispositivo aparece uma mensagem dizendo (**O aplicativo não foi instalado**).

Se eu gerar o apk em uma versão anterior do android, ele funciona normalmente..

a parte que circulei na imagem não era solicitada na versão anterior do meu android, será que pode ser algo relacionado a isso?

Comment: Creio que seja para teste. Por que você não tenta gerar um apk normal, sem assinatura?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu estava passando pelo mesmo problema esses dias, marquei as duas opções e consegui gerar a apk e testar normalmente. Descobri que é um novo mecanismo de assinatura introduzido no Android 7.0 com alguns novos recursos por questões de segurança. Enfim você **deve marcar** tanto **V1** quanto **V2**, para não ter esses problemas.

Informações mais aprofundadas: [apk signature v2](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2)